# Community Only User

Tags: community, user, customer-community, user-management, userlicense

We are making a community for our customers. Users are provisioned during SSO. BTW, users should be Community **Only**. I.E. should not have access to real SF application or edit existing settings. For every user a contact created on some predefined account and every user has profile with pre-defined 'Customer Community' license. Then this profile is added to community allowed list.

Am I Correct, that used license is exactly community only? 
Is it correct approach to create community users through contacts, profiles and license for every community user (would it clash with exisitng users)? A bit confusing relation of user and contact

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the schema that Salesforce itself has decided.  To create a User you need to have a Contact first and that contact has to be linked to an Account (account as the parent and contact as the child)  This contact in turn is related to the User itself.( user - child, contact - parent).

As according to the documentaion:

> Internal licenses such as CRM and Force.com are typically sold to employees who work inside the customer organization. As you embark on your journey to become a customer company, we believe that your employees will be key to your success. That’s why any of your employees and users with a Salesforce internal license can access external Communities at no extra charge. All internal licenses are supported except the Chatter External license.
>
> External user licenses are targeted at people outside your company, such as partners or customers. External licenses include legacy portal licenses and Communities licenses. Users with a portal license can access both portals and communities; users with a community license can only access Communities.

Find more here- https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/02/salesforce-communities-licenses.html

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0

Comment: Let me know if I am wrong. 

I am a company - MyC. 
My client - CC. We have an appropriate account CC in salesforce for this client. 
My client company people are stored as contacts in CC account.
Community users should be assigned to some account as well, so the new account is needed for new community users.
Looks like I have one more client (because of a new account MyC). Looks like I'm working with myself. But this account purpose is only to contain community users (my clients, but not my workers). 

So real client companies accounts and community user accounts are being mixed up

Comment: For the company CC, there are suppose 10 contacts, 5 of them are community users. You do not have to create another account for these community users, just go the contact, click the button 'Manage External User' and enable the contact for the community. This will not create another user but will allow the existing user to log into community. This contact is now both external and internal user. Please refer above links for more info. Let me know if this was what you were asking.

Comment: Yes you are right we can enable the external user, but we are not going to do it manually. There too many existing users. Moreover, community users are provisioned by SSO. And it is impossible to find out to which account user should be connected during provisioning.  It is impossible to detect is there already such user in SF. 
SAML assertion contains AccountNumber attribute. Account to which new community user should be connected (it is CommunityAccount id).
But this new community user is not my worker, it is my client but belongs to my community account. Look like I am going in wrong way